# moderncv: Changing font family removes the boldness of the titles and headers

Tags: fonts, moderncv, bold

Why does the change of the font family (from sans to roman) remove the boldness of sections headers and entries titles?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[12pt,roman]{moderncv}
\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\name{Diaa}{Abidou}
\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \section{Education}
    \cvitem{Title}{Some Title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: because the font setup of moderncv is a mess. You should better reset it after loading the style to whatever font you really want to use (and better don't load fontspec yourself).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I would be grateful if you could tell me how to reset the font setup in view of my MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment the codes of `\usepackage[tuenc]{font spec}` you will get the bf shape again! The reason is that in the `fontspec` package, it doesn't set the shape of `bfseries` font!

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[12pt,roman]{moderncv}
%\usepackage[tuenc]{fontspec}

\moderncvstyle{banking}
\name{Diaa}{Abidou}
\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \section{Education}
    \cvitem{Title}{Some Title}
\end{document}
```

The following is the PDF style
[image]